# How to define a method with two arguments in a python class?

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I have a piece of code that works fine, now for some reasons (making a package connected to jupyter) I need to rewrite it as a class and methods. I need to get my data from a file, then extract two lists out of it, then do some operations upon them, and at the end sum them somehow. This is the scheme of the code that I wrote already:

```
import numpy as np
class Tv:
    def __init__(self):
    def set_data(self, df):
        self.data = df
    def split_df(self, df):
        self.data1 = df[(df.prop == '1')].reset_index()
        self.data2 = df[(df.prop == '2')].reset_index()
        event = ['2004-05-16', '2004-05-27']
        list1, list2 = list()
        for i in range(0, len(event)):
            temp = self.data1[self.data1.event == event[i]].reset_index()
            temp2 = self.data2[self.data2.event == event[i]].reset_index()
            list1.append(temp)
            list2.append(temp2)
        self.list1 = list1
        self.list2 = list2
        return (self.list1, self.list2)
    def sum_lists(self, list1, list2):
        summed_list = np.sum(list1, list2)
        return summed_list
```

As you can see, I need to extract list1 and list2 from the given data frame (df) and then after doing some modifications on each of them (that I removed for the sake of shortness) I sum them up and return the sum. Now the problem is that I do not know how to define the summed_lists method properly. I am very new in OOP and everything is a bit confusing to me.

this is the error I get:

```
'Tv' object has no attribute 'sum_lists'
```

Comment: You will get an indentation error beacuse of your `init` method. Please correct that.

Comment: The code you show here doesn't have valid indentation; I suspect an indentation issue in your actual code as well.

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]. As it stands, this code won't even *compile* which is a pretty low bar in Python. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) are some tips on how to format your code in stack overflow questions.

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` are attributes, there's no need to pass them as parameters. You can just use `np.sum(self.list1, self.list2)`

Comment: `list1, list2 = list()` gets an error.

Comment: I do not know what to put in __init__  because I use my dataframe to get the needed atributes. why __init__ cannot be empty?